# Can R Officer Be Used to Output Regression Tables in a Specific Style?

Tags: r, r-markdown, regression, officer, officedown

My prior understanding was that the ability to utilize Microsoft Word Table styles is only available in the `officedown` package, but syntax like

```
read_docx(path = "reports/template.docx") %>%
body_add_flextable(my_ft) %>%
print(target = "reports/example_template.docx")
```

suggests some ability to format Word `flextable` objects, e.g. those one would use for outputting regressions, according to Word document Table-styles? Is this feature available in the `officer` package? If so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `body_add_table()`:

```
doc <- read_docx()
doc <- body_add_table(doc, iris, style = "table_template")
print(doc, target = tempfile(fileext = ".docx") )
```

But flextable objects cannot be associated with a specific Word table template. To style a flextable object, you can only use flextable functions.

Comment: Thank you, but can I adapt this to output ```flextable``` objects, e.g. regression tables etc., in Word formats, rather than just ```data.frames```?

Comment: No, this is not the way it works with flextable

Comment: Right so the answer to my question is really "no, ```flextable``` objects cannot be exported into a Word document with a specific Table format", but I have approved your answer because it is closest to what I wanted and may be helpful to others.

Comment: I've updated the answer

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted the question and will upvote it when I have enough credit on this site. I have asked a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70583223/how-to-combine-flextable-and-officedown-to-output-flextable-objects-with-a-parti

Comment: to me it's the same question. flextable objects cannot be associated with a specific Word table template.

Comment: Right, so the recommended procedure for ```flextable``` objects is to format them in Word manually after outputting them with ```officer```?

Comment: No, you can format flextable as you want, with r functions, see https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-gallery/gallery/ and https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/

Comment: Thank you. Many of the ```flextable``` examples are impressive, but I find that I must often make some slight changes to exported Word tables, e.g. to the Table border style for the footer of the table to make it a double-line, changing fonts, etc. In ```officer```, as you pointed out in your answer, I can make those changes by specifying a Word Table-style in advance and using that template with a data.frame. Is it impossible to use pre-specified Word formats for changes like that for ```flextable``` objects?

Comment: the answer is still no