# How to combine flextable and officedown to output flextable objects with a particular Word Table style?

Tags: r, r-markdown, regression, flextable, officedown

I am interested in outputting `flextable` objects (mainly summary statistics and regression tables) according to a particular Word Table-style. Based on prior Stack Overflow questions and documentation, e.g.

[Applying a Word style (table or paragraph) to flextable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49823259/applying-a-word-style-table-or-paragraph-to-flextable-object?rq=1)

I believe this is not possible in `flextable` alone. However, the new `officedown` package documentation says that it supports both Word Table styles and `flextable` objects.

Is it now possible to output say, `flextable` regression tables, according to a particular Word style using `officedown`? I could find no examples of this in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can now. See documentation here: https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/rendering.html

under '3.3 Rmarkdown' the knitr chunk options for specifying the word style names are given (tab.style & tab.cap.style).  you would need to setup it all in your template word document.

Comment: Based on the answer I received from the package maintainer and the documentation of Package updates (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flextable/news/news.html), I believe that this capability is still not available, but I will make a test and if it works, happy to give you the credited answer.

Comment: In particular, @Kristy Robledo, have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70581393/can-r-officer-be-used-to-output-regression-tables-in-a-specific-style